# Django Problem: manage.py runserver erorr message

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, python-3.x

I'm coding my first django project with python3 and when I close my server I get this error message:

I'm trying to figure it out but I can't find a solution. Please help. Thanks!

```html
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have also started learning Python and Django recently. I have also encountered situation like this.

In the error you have shown, while creating database, it is generating error.

In my opinion, better to take it slow and just run Django project once installed without any of your code.

then, gradually increase. once you add single app, better to migrate to verify everything is working fine. before creating another, with that you can easily identify where you got problem from.

or just create test cases.